# KineticJS: Animation with a Number of single Images?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I have 10 png images which I want to display as an animation on a canvas. This should be done similar to how KineticJS does sprite animations. The only difference is that my frames are not part of one big sprite image. Instead my images (frames) are in single png files.

**Is there are way how I can load the image frames into KineticJS and then play them as an animation?**

Answer (score 0):

You may change `image` property of `Kinetic.Image` in any animation loop.

Or if `Sprite` class is what you need you can:

1. Create big canvas element.
2. Draw 10 images into it (make one big image)
3. Then use it as `image` for `Sprite`

Comment: Which solution has better performance. I want to drag, move and resize the animation on the canvas.

Comment: Not sure. You should test your case.